# linear programming - how to write standard form

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

i've created a small linear optimization modell (simplex) in excel. it assigns products to shelfs and minimizes the total distance. My math skills are rusty. how do i write this LP-Modell in the standard form (linear function to be minimized, Problem constraints, Non-negative variables)

[Thats how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOkRS.png)

I read several examples, i am confused. In every example there is just one matrice. My model is using 2.. I really tried to understand it.

Constraints: for each product one shelf, each self just one product

thank you!

$\large{\texttt{Edit}}$

When i add more products/shelfes $(n)$ the number of variables grows exponentially $(n^2)$. I think integer programming is not the fasted way to slove this. The hungarian algorithm would be the bedder/faster choice to slove this right?

[How the matrix would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhCn6.png)

Comment: It's not clear what any of the constraints actually are.  If you want to minimize the distance, why can't you just put all the products in a pile?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems like the question is to amateurish for this board. I've added information about the constraints. Would be great if anyone would help me.

Comment: @bartman99 The hungrian method is a method to solve integer problems. The model which I have written at the answer is right. To solve it there a several methods available-one amoung others is the hungrian method

Comment: thank you i understand. why is the written program deleted? can you add it again please

Comment: @bartman99 I have undeleted the answer. I thought you wasn´t interested in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model is not a real linear problem since the decision variables are binary.

The program is

$\text{min} \ \ z=100x_{11}+50x_{12}+200x_{21}+100x_{22}$

$x_{11}+x_{21}=1$

$x_{12}+x_{22}=1$

$x_{11}+x_{12}=1$

$x_{21}+x_{22}=1$

$x_{ij} \in \{0,1\} \ \forall \ \ i,j=1, 2$

This problem can be solved with the solver. I got the solution $x_{11}^*=x_{22}^*=1,x_{12}^*=x_{21}^*=0, z^*=200$

Comment: thank you a lot. So right name would be integer programming.

Comment: @bartman99 Yes, that´s true. Is the rest comprehensible as well?